# iOS UISearchController: Wait until UISearchController is dismissed after canceling search

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, searchbar, dispatch-async

I have a `UISearchController` that is dismissed when the user clicks the cancel button. After the user clicks the cancel button, I want the `UISearchController` to be dismissed first then the showNewTableData method needs to be called. Here is the code that I am using that works.

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self showNewTableData];
    });
}

- (void)showNewTableData {
      if (self.searchController.active && self.searchController.searchBar.text.length > 0) {
         // show search data
      } else {
         // show non search data
      }
    }
```

Using `dispatch_async` seems to accomplish my requirements very well, but not sure if this is a good idea. If I don't use `dispatch_async`, I will end up showing search data because the search bar hasn't finished clearing text and it is still active. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as how you're trying to do a UI change, its fine to do this in the main thread.

Comment: So it's okay to add new data in the UITableView in the  dispatch_async block, correct? Sorry, just want to be 100% certain.

Comment: you can add data from anywhere, the issue with the dispatch is specific to your problem because you want something to happen before the next

Now if we're talking specifically about the table view, its probably best to simply change the data source of the table view upon a search starting or ending, something along the lines of results and filteredResults and changing those according to the state of the search.